# attache function to other function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a simple requirement, I need add the same code to hundreds of other JavaScript functions, the code can be executed at the end of the function, is there a handy way of doing it, like attach an function to another function dynamically, I think yes, because JavaScript is so powerful and too powerful, any ideas?

Note, I need dynamically assign new code or function to existing functions without change existing function's code, please give a solid solution, I can do it in hacky way, but no hacky way please!

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a reduced version of the code you already have with a concrete example? As it is, we cannot provide a specific answer and be sure that's what you are looking for. This will result in tons of comments.

Comment: Are you wanting to add the function call to a specific set of functions or are you wanting it to be added to all functions?

Comment: you can wrap the reused code in a function and call it within an other function. However if you aim reusability you might look at Javascript "classes" (prototyping)

Comment: @artymcfly yes, that's i want, just add couple line of code to a few existing functions in javassript

Comment: @kasper,  the new code is just 2 lines, i dont want to create a function then put it into the existing function, too lame

Comment: What's wrong with a function that only has 2 lines of logic? I think you really need to post an example like stated in the comment from blex

Comment: @kasper, just too lame of doing it, javascript should be able to do it, I can do it in prototype, but I want do it in a solid way, i am doing it for serious business

Comment: You might want to look at an instrumentation library like [istanbul](https://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/) to see how they get under the hood.

Comment: When you say you `can do it in a hacky way`, could you include a code snippet of the "hacky way"? Also, could you define what you are looking for in `no hacky way`. Also, are you looking to changing the code snippets added dynamically during code running, perhaps only running certain code snippets once or twice? Or are you looking to continuously appending additional code while running? Lastly, your feedback on the answers below, how they do not fit your needs would help us to help you

Comment: @artymcfly, thanks, I've got a solution now, cheers!

Comment: You should post your solution and accept it then =] Congrats at that!

Comment: @artymcfly, not a fancy way, just manually added the function to each existing function, it's not handy,but solid and more maintainable for future developer to working on it, so, yes, keep it simple and easy to understand, if I am doing something for my own project, I'll try the prototype ways of doing it. cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method that comes to mind is simply create another function:

```
function primaryFunction() {
    // ...
    utilityMethod();
}
function otherPrimaryFunction() {
    // ...
    utilityMethod();
}

function utilityMethod() { ... }
```

Now `utilityMethod()` gets called from the end of each other primary function.

---

There's also a method which requires more code refactoring but is better in the long term: classes/prototypes.

Essentially, you have one "constructor" function which takes a number of parameters for the "class" and returns an class-like object:

```
function constructor(someClassField, anotherField) {
    this.aField = someClassField;
    this.fieldTwo = anotherField;
    return this;
}
```

Now if you call this and pass some parameters, you get a class out:

```
var myClass = new constructor("1", "2");
myClass.aField == "1";
myClass.fieldTwo == "2";
```

So: If you define your utility method as above, then you can use this: for every primary function you instantiate a new instance of the constructor, with the final code looking like this:

```
function constructor(primaryFunction) {
    this.function = primaryFunction;
    this.call = function() {
        this.function();
        utilityMethod();
    }
    this.call();
    return this;
}

function utilityMethod() { ... }

var primaryMethod = new constructor(function() { ... });
```

The creation of `primaryMethod` now **automatically** calls the primary function followed by the utility method, before returning the object so you can re-call both if you want to.

Comment: thanks, but this is not what i want, i want to dynamicly assgn new code or function to existing funciton without changing the existing function code, dude

Comment: @KevinSimple I can't think of a way that's possible. You're going to need to make some fairly heavy edits to your code either way.

Comment: i don't think you are right, JavaScript was design to do this, remember, it's a dynamic language not like c#, it compile and run nearly at the same time, that's far more powerful

Comment: @KevinSimple Not necessarily. Compile time has no effect on the power of the language: only the features built into the language affect that. As far as I can tell there is no feature built in to allow this therefore you have to do it some other way.